# SQL: How to implement insert/update of multiple data for specific table in sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

First of all the question might be misleading for I don't know how to put into words my exact problem.

I'm planning to make an attendance system where a user would be able to time-in/time-out. I created two tables, first the user table(containing user's information) and the timestamp table(containing the time-in and time-out). Now the problem is I don't know how to implement the timestamp table to be connected to a specific user and be able to store multiple time-ins and time-outs.

Please let me know if need to clarify some things for I'm not sure if the info I've given is enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't all you need a table with three columns, a userid column, a time column and a flag for whether it's a time-in or a time-out?

Comment: @TrippKinetics So each time the a user would time-in or time-out it would create an entry in the table? How do I make the userid column? Would this be needing the application of foreign key/primary key?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Additional question though, would it be better for me to make a two different tables for time-in and time-out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique user identifier column to the user table and make it your primary key.  Add the same column to the attendance table but do not make it a primary key.  It will be this common column that will allow you to relate your users to their attendance. You may also want a unique identifier on the attendance table if you are not going to set the time out until later.

```
CREATE TABLE  `User` (
    `UserID` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`UserID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `UserAttendance` (
    `UserID` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `InTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
    `OutTimestamp` timestamp NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`)
        REFERENCES `User`(`UserID`)
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I've got an idea how would I implement it with your answer.